# GeometryReader and ZStack to product screenshot

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader, zstack

My goal: To use geometry reader and a screenshot function (already written) to grab just the small portion of an image that falls behind a close button.

Setup: I have a ZStack with an `Image` and a smaller button overtop of it (it is a system image for this example). Currently, I have the close button aligned to the top of the background image and everything looks good at first glance.

However, when the close button is tapped, I need to grab a screenshot of the close button itself (matching frame and size).

Everything worked when my `ZStack` had a `.center` alignment, but now that I have set `alignment: .top`, my screenshot is still occurring in the center of the image.

How can I shift the `GeometryReader` that encompasses the close button to allow for the screenshot to be of the close button (and a bit of extra background behind it) when it is tapped?

My Code:

```
struct ImageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Image("ZoomedBuzz")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 80))
                    .border(Color.blue)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        let globalImage = takeScreenshot(origin: geo.frame(in: .global).origin,
                                                         size: geo.size)
                        print(globalImage)
                    }
            }
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .top)
        }
    }
}
```

Taking the screenshot:

```
extension UIView {
    var renderedImage: UIImage {
        // rect of capture
        let rect = self.bounds
        // create the context of bitmap
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.layer.render(in: context)
        // get a image from current context bitmap
        let capturedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return capturedImage
    }
}

extension View {
    func takeScreenshot(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        hosting.view.frame = window.frame
        window.addSubview(hosting.view)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return hosting.view.renderedImage
    }
}
```

[image: Simulator Screen]

Desired Result (but taken at the top of the `ZStack`):

[image: Desired Result]

Current Result (screenshot being taken in the middle of the background image centered with the `ZStack`):

[image: Current Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the GeometryReader to be close around the button instead of capturing the whole screen you can set it as the buttons background.

Unfortunately I don't know how your screenshot method works therefore I couldn't verify that it's working with your setup, but now you can simply screenshot the whole GeometryReader's frame.

```
struct ImageView: View {
    
    @State private var geo: GeometryProxy!
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Image("ZoomedBuzz")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 80))
                .border(Color.blue)
                .background(rectReader())
                .onTapGesture {
                    let globalImage = takeScreenshot(origin: geo.frame(in: .global).origin,
                                                     size: geo.size)
                    print(globalImage)
                }
        }
    }
    
    private func rectReader() -> some View {
        return GeometryReader { geometry -> AnyView in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.geo = geometry
            }
            return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(Color.clear))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks works super well for setting the geometry reader to fit the button itself. However the screenshot is still being taken in the wrong place. I updated my question to include the screenshot func as well.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it looks like the issue within my screenshot function. I am looking into it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but did you figured it out?)